# Git describe command returns different value after no change whatsoever

Tags: git, bitbucket

In my Bitbucket project I have 3 repositories. In all of them i use tags to mark versions, for example: "1.0.23" or "1.0.24".

Everything worked fine, when I used "git describe" I got the tags like mentioned above.
After I came back to work after a long weekend, one of the repositories started to make problems: When I use "git describe" there, I get something like this: "1.0.24-2-8a3asf". I found out it's like I'd use "git describe --long".

There's also the problem, that the "git describe" command doesn't give me the latest tag. For example:

- Merge A (older) has tag "1.0.23"
- Merge B (newer) has tag "1.0.24" and "1.0.25"

The "git describe" command gives me the long version of "1.0.23". When using "git describe --tags" on the other hand, I get "1.0.24", the short version but still not the latest tag.

Comment: *How* are you creating these tags? Can show an example?

Comment: @RomainValeri Either per Bitbucket feature, adding the tag to a commit. I also use git commands:
- cloning repo
- setting and pushing tags
´´´git tag -a 1.0.24 -m 'foobar'; git push origin 1.0.24´´´

Comment: I'm asking because I was suspecting a problem with part of your tags being annotated tags and others being lightweight ones. Your CLI example makes annotated ones, but bitbucket?

Comment: @RomainValeri The thing is, both work. Both ways work in the other repositories, both worked on that one repository. But I checked just a few minutes ago and got the same result, either way.